# click event on span in ipad safari

Tags: html, angular, ipad, safari, click

I am trying to call a function on `click` event on `<span>` in safari browser (iPad). but nothing happens when I click on it. I have tried touchstart, touchend and (ngModelChange) but it didnt worked.

Here's the code:

```
<span class="store-wrapper" (click)="clickToSayHello()"></span>
```

In ts file: 
the function simply shows an alert. There's no logic as such.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @AdritaSharma ma'm please find the code above. I have edited the question.

Comment: Does it work on other browsers? Or on your desktop?

Comment: yep it works fine. It just shows an alert.

Comment: May be your span is getting overridden by any other element.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to check that? @AdritaSharma

Comment: Inspect and check